# ¿Como aplicar una misma accion a dos elementos diferentes por medio de jquery? [.Click]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaria aplicar una accion de reseteo de los campos de mi formulario y me gustaria que al momento de dar en cancelat en el span de la "x" me devuelva el border originar si es que lo cierra o lo cancela con errores. Actualmente me funciona solo con la "x" de cerra, si hace el reseteo pero quiero que no solo con span sino con buttons funcione.

Codigo Actual:

```
$('span').click(function (event) {
    $('#selCertificacionP option').remove();
    $('#selCertificacion option').remove();
    $("#txtNombreP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtRFCP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtDireccionP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtColoniaP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtCiudadP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtEstadoP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtPaisP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtCodigoP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtTelefonoP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#selCertificacionP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtFolioP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtFecInicioP").css("border-color", "white");
    $("#txtFecFinP").css("border-color", "white");
});
```

Me gustaria pasarle dos paramteros o tres parametros al evento .click de jquery, para que de ahi mismo se lo aplique al boton o cualquier elemento que yo decida.

Comment: Quieres añadir el mismo listener al evento click de dos elementos, o quieres gatillar el evento click en dos elementos?

Comment: @amenadiel gatillar el evento click en dos elementos?

Comment: Podrías probar `$('span,button').trigger('click');`

Comment: @amenadiel esa funcion tambien es valida con id´s?

Comment: Claro, todo lo que separes por coma en un selector, amplía la selección `$('#cancelar,#resetear').trigger('click');`

Comment: @amenadiel cual seria la diferencia de tu primer comentario?

Comment: @x-rw en que añadir el mismo listener tendría la forma `$('span,button').click(function() { ... });` (ambos hacen lo mismo al clickearlos) y la segunda, como mostré, significa gatillar el mismo evento en ambos, lo que puede a su vez llamar a dos listeners absolutamente distintos.  En este caso, es posible que los listeners sean iguales, pero eso es anecdótico. Podría ser que el botón vacíe el formulario mientras que el span sólo les cambia el color de borde.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas,  te aconsejo usar una clase css padre en el formulario.

Digamos que tenemos esto en html:

```
 <form id="miFormulario" class=""> 
   <input type="text" placheholder="campo 1"/>
   <input type="text" placheholder="campo 2" />
   <button onclick="resetearFormulario()" >Resetear</button> 
 </form>
```

Ahora queremos darle un aspecto diferente si tener que escribir tanto jquery. Además separamos código css del de javascript. Podemos jugar con los valores de class del formulario.

En nuestra hoja de estilos tendríamos:

```
#miFormulario.fill input{} /* aplica a todos los inputs */
#miFormulario.fill textarea{} /* aplica a todos los textarea*/

#miFormulario.clean input{} /* aplica a todos los inputs */
#miFormulario.clean textarea{} /* aplica a todos los textarea*/
```

Haríamos algo parecido a esto en javascript:

```
<script>
   function resetearFormulario(){
      $('#miFormulario')[0].reset();//reseteamos 

      $('#miFormulario').attr('class','clean');
      /* se puede hacer de muchas formas por ejemplo
      $('#miFormulario').removeClass('fill').addClass('clean');  
      */
   }
</script>
```

Automáticamente estaremos reseteando el formulario y aplicando los estilos correspondientes.

Tambien puedes hacer uso del operador de selección "," de esta forma:

```
$('span').click(function (event) {
  $('#selCertificacionP option,#selCertificacion option').remove(); 
  $("#txtNombreP,#txtRFCP,#txtDireccionP,#txtColoniaP,#txtCiudadP,#txtEstadoP,#txtPaisP,#txtCodigoP,#txtTelefonoP,#selCertificacionP,#txtFolioP,#txtFecInicioP,#txtFecFinP").css("border-color", "white");

});
```

Pero te lo desaconsejo , crear ids  porque sí no es una buena idea , utiliza una clase , así :

```
$('span').click(function(){
 $('.myselects option').remove();
 $('.myInputs').css('border-color','white');
});
```

Tu pregunta es muy amplia ya que tiene muchas soluciones posibles , pero siempre es mejor delegar a cada cosa su trabajo , usar una clase css con el estilo a aplicar suele ser lo más optimo y re utilizable.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Coloca los elementos separados por coma: por ejemplo

`$("#txtNombreP, #txtRFCP, #txtDireccionP").css("border-color", "white");`

Comment: Se aplaude la intención de responder y ayudar.  Por favor agrega una explicación de por qué o cómo tu solución resuelve el problema del AP. Para más información, lee [answer]. Un saludo.